# Finding the partitions of a set which respect to some rules

Tags: multisets, set-partition

Let's take two elements from different domains.

The first element `f ∈ {a, b, c, d} and s ∈ in N`

I also have a list of relationship between these elements which can be represented as it follows

```
+--------+--------+
| f      | s      |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| c      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 4      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 5      |
+--------+--------+
```

Two elements are in relationship if they are listed in that table on the same row. So for example a and 1 are related.

The scope is to partition the bigger set which contains {a, b, c, d, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in smaller sets which are

- mutually exclusive
- The union of all the partition sets must equal the initial set
- Each partition set must contain all the elements which are related together.

This means that it's acceptable to have 3 partitions like:

```
{a, b, 1, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4, 5}
```

But we cannot have

```
{a, b, 1}, {c, 2, 3}, {d, 4, 5}
```

Since a is related to 2 so they must be in the same set.

I would like to find one or more acceptable partitions. I found the solution manually but I couldn't get the theory which is leading to the solution.

Comment: An user said that "the whole problem sounds like graph theory. Aren't you just looking for connected subgraphes in the graph with nodes {f union s} and edges whenever there is an entry in the table?". Is it correct?

Comment: So what's your question? It appears you've found an acceptable partition. Do you need more? Do you want to count how many there are? Do you want an algorithm for determining when acceptable partitions exist?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: yes, I would like to find one or more acceptable partitions but I found the solution manually. I couldn't get the theory which is leading to the solution..

Comment: You should make that clear in your question, and not just in the comments here. State clearly what you're asking for, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: thanks, I will edit

Comment: I got the suggestion that "what you are looking for is the connected components of the graph whose the edges are given by the rows in your table."